# How to update a table with a value calculated from a different table and the one being edited?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is a car rental company database. Clients pay weekly.

Payments should start 7 days after pickup (inspectionDate).

Some, but not all, weekly fees are wrongly scheduled to be due before 7 days of the inspection, but they are all 7 days apart from each other.

The query below gives me the difference in days from pickup to the 2nd weekly fee due date. (1st payment is before pickup)

```sql
SELECT 
    r.id,
    CAST( i.creationDate AS DATE ) AS inspectionDate,
    CAST( wf.dueDate AS DATE ) AS dueDate,
    DATEDIFF( DAY, CAST( i.creationDate AS DATE ), CAST( wf.dueDate AS DATE ) ) AS daysDiff
FROM 
    rental r 
    JOIN weeklyFee wf ON wf.rentalId = r.id
    JOIN inspection i ON i.rentalId= r.id
WHERE 
    i.eventType = 'pickup'
    AND wf.number = 2 --#1 is paid on pickup or before
    AND DATEDIFF( DAY, CAST( i.creationDate AS DATE ), CAST( wf.dueDate AS DATE ) ) < 7
```

There are weeklyFee entries for every payment in the year long plan. It's rental 1:N payments, all of which must be updated (except the first).

1 rental has 1 inspection.

**How can I update only the series of weekly fees that are scheduled to start before 1 week past inspection date ?**
i.e. If the second weeklyFee is less than 7 days after the inspection, add the necessary amount of days ( 7 - daysDiff ) to all weeklyFees associated with a particular rental

Query sample: (incorrect entries only, filtered by the last query line)

[image: query]

Inspection table sample: (fixed date)

[image: inspection]

Weekly Fee table sample:

[image: payment]

The first two lines from weeklyFee (last image) should have dueDate moved foward 1 day.

The second pair 3 days. The third 4 days.

Comment: For future reference, please don't use images for data, use formatted text, ideally for sample data use DDL/DML statements. Not using images allows people to copy and paste the data out to test possible solutions.

Comment: even for now , please update your question with plain text sample data and desired output , thanks

Comment: please simply say, which column you want to update by what conditions?

Comment: if ( (dueDate - inspectionDate) < 7 ) 

then { dueDate += 7 - (dueDate - inspectionDate) }

else { dueDate = dueDate }

Answer (score 0):

if the following gives the correct newDueDate...

```
SELECT 
    r.id,
    CAST( i.creationDate AS DATE ) AS inspectionDate,
    CAST( wf.dueDate AS DATE ) AS dueDate,
    DATEDIFF( DAY, CAST( i.creationDate AS DATE ), CAST( wf.dueDate AS DATE ) ) AS daysDiff, 
    --
    wf.number,
    wf.dueDate,    
    (7-(datediff(day, i.creationDate, wf.dueDate)%7))%7 as daystoadd,
    dateadd(day, (7-(datediff(day, i.creationDate, wf.dueDate)%7))%7  /*<-- days to add*/,wf.dueDate) as newdueDate
FROM 
    rental r --is this needed ??
    JOIN weeklyFee wf ON wf.rentalId = r.id --..join these two tables only..?
    JOIN inspection i ON i.rentalId= r.id
WHERE 
    i.eventType = 'pickup'
    AND wf.number >= 2 --number 2 and on
    and (7-(datediff(day, i.creationDate, wf.dueDate)%7))%7 <> 0 -- days to add <> 0.. or better >=1 ?
    --or days diff is not 7....
    --and 7-(datediff(day, i.creationDate, wf.dueDate)%7) <> 7
    --AND DATEDIFF( DAY, CAST( i.creationDate AS DATE ), CAST( wf.dueDate AS DATE ) ) < 7;
```

...then you can turn it into an update

```
update  wf
set dueDate = dateadd(day, (7-(datediff(day, i.creationDate, wf.dueDate)%7))%7  /*<-- days to add*/,wf.dueDate) --as newdueDate 
FROM 
    rental r --is this needed ??
    JOIN weeklyFee wf ON wf.rentalId = r.id --..join these two tables only..?
    JOIN inspection i ON i.rentalId= r.id
WHERE 
    i.eventType = 'pickup'
    AND wf.number >= 2 --number 2 and on
    and (7-(datediff(day, i.creationDate, wf.dueDate)%7))%7 <> 0 -- days to add <> 0.. or better >=1 ?
    --or days diff is not 7....
    --and 7-(datediff(day, i.creationDate, wf.dueDate)%7) <> 7
    --AND DATEDIFF( DAY, CAST( i.creationDate AS DATE ), CAST( wf.dueDate AS DATE ) ) < 7;
```